# Calling Assembly functions in C, reverse a string

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, cpu-registers

I am trying to write a c program that will call an assembly function to reverse a string. However, I am having a hard time just getting the assembly code to iterate through the string to find the end character "0".

My C code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// These functions will be implemented in assembly:
//
void strrev(char *str) ;

int main(){
    char *str1;
    str1 = strdup("Hello World");
    strrev(str1);
    printf("str1 reversed: \"%s\"\n", str1) ;
    free(str1);
    return 0;
}
```

any my assembly code is simply:

```
; File: strrev.asm
; A subroutine called from C programs.
; Parameters: string A
; Result: String is reversed and returned.


    SECTION .text
    global strrev
_strrev: nop
strrev:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    ; registers ebx,esi, and edi must be saved if used
    push ebx
    push edi

    xor esi, esi    
    xor eax, eax
    lea ecx, [esp+8]    ; load the start of the array into ecx
    jecxz   end     ; jump if [ecx] is zero
    mov edi, ecx

reverseLoop:
    cmp byte[edi], 0
    je  end
    inc     edi 
    inc eax
    jmp reverseLoop

end:
    pop edi     ; restore registers
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp    ; take down stack frame
    pop ebp
    ret
```

All I want this code to do right now is simply iterate through the string until it finds the end inside of reverseLoop. However, if I try to use gdb and step through the program, it seems to fail immediately after looking at the first character "H".

Running with GDB with a break at line 25 while displaying the edi register with "display/c $edi" produces the following output:

```
(gdb) 
reverseLoop () at strrev.asm:25
25      cmp byte[edi], 0
1: /c $edi = 72 'H'
```

Which is right, but if I step through down to inc edi, edi immediately becomes incorrect. It should be "E" since the second character in "Hello World" is "e". But, the gdb output lists it as "I":

```
27      inc     edi 
1: /c $edi = 72 'H'
(gdb) 
28      inc eax
1: /c $edi = 73 'I'
```

Am I doing something wrong when I am iterating through the edi register?

Comment: By the way, is this on a 32 or 64 bit system? If it's a 64-bit system you drop the top 32 bits of the address, making the pointer point to somewhere completely different place in memory.

Comment: The first argument is at [ebp + 8] NOT [esp + 8]. You should also use MOV instea of LEA, otherwise you get, `((char*)$ebp + 8)` instead of `(*(char**)($ebp + 8))`. Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the *contents* of the `edi` register as a character, but the contents is actually an address. What you really want is to display what the address in `edi` points to.

Maybe try

```
display *((char *) $edi)
```

Comment: So is there a certain flag I can use when debugging to convert that address to its respective character in the array?

Comment: @user2252004 Updated my answer, please try it.

Comment: The result of that display on the first iteration is: Breakpoint 1, reverseLoop () at strrev.asm:25
25  cmp byte[edi], 0
1: *((char *) $edi) = 120 'x'

Comment: I seemed to fix the issue by applying the recommendation of the other answer, which was changing lea ecx, [esp + 8] to mov ecx, [ebp+8]. With that change, the characters print out correctly. Thanks for the assistance :). I am sure ill be back as now I have to figure out how to reverse them :P.

Answer (score 0):

How about `mov cl, [ebp+8]` instead of `lea ecx, [esp+8]`?

Comment: And then change all references to "ecx" to "cl?"

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.  It should be `lea ecx, [ebp+8]`. (I've confused `str` and `*str`)

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong again.  `mov ecx, [ebp+8]` is right.  It's the `str` in C.  And your `cmp byte [edi], ...` is `*str` in C.

Comment: Your answer along with the other one seemed to work. Not sure why I was using lea, just saw it somewhere and it worked once before in a different program I was working on. Changing it to mov corrected the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After the function prologue sets up **EBP**, the first argument is at `[ebp + 8]` *NOT* `[esp + 8]`. Since entering `strrev()`, you've pushed EBP, EBX, EDI and thus moved ESP by the time you wanted to access the first argument to the function. You should also use **MOV** instea of **LEA**, otherwise you get `((char*)$ebp + 8)` instead of `(*(char**)($ebp + 8))`.

Your original `mainLoop` tried to implement `strlen()` by processing 4 bytes at a time but the way you were detecting the `'\0'` byte and maintaining the string length count was only correct if done one byte at a time.

Another, unrelated bug was that you stored (length-of-string / 2) in **EAX** but were also using **AL** as temporary storage while swapping characters. **AL** being the lowest byte of **EAX**, the string length got clobbered and the character swapping loop wouldn't terminate after the correct number of iterations.

Take a look at the patch below, where I fixed the code from an earlier version of your question:

```
--- strrev.asm.orig 2013-05-06 20:25:58.000497875 +0800
+++ strrev.asm  2013-05-06 20:26:29.583835308 +0800
@@ -17,16 +17,37 @@

     xor esi, esi    
     xor eax, eax
-    lea ecx, [esp+8]    ; load the start of the array into ecx
+    mov ecx, [ebp+8]    ; load the start of the array into ecx
     jecxz   end     ; jump if [ecx] is zero
-    mov edi, ecx
+
+mainLoop:
+    add eax, 1      ; icn eax would work as well
+    add     ecx, 1      
+    mov dl, [ecx]  ; load ecx
+    cmp dl, 0      ; compare with 0
+    je  reverseLoop     ; if ecx is zero, we're done
+    jmp mainLoop        ; if ecx isn't zero, keep looping
+

 reverseLoop:
-    cmp byte[edi], 0
-    je  end
-    inc     edi 
-    inc eax
-    jmp reverseLoop
+    mov ecx, [ebp + 8]  ; reload the start of the array into ecx
+    mov esi, ecx    ; esi points to start of array
+    add ecx, eax
+    mov edi, ecx    
+    dec edi ;edi points to end of array
+    shr eax, 1  ;eax is the count
+    jz  end ; if string is 0 or 1 chars long, jump to end
+
+reverseLoop_1:
+
+    mov cl, [esi]   ;load initial array
+    mov bl, [edi]   ;load end of array
+    mov [esi], bl   ;swap
+    mov [edi], cl
+    inc esi
+    dec edi
+    dec eax     ;loop
+    jnz reverseLoop_1   

 end:
     pop edi     ; restore registers
```